# Adjusting a code to add a secondary explanatory variable to a table

Tags: r, group-by

This is my first time using R. I am attempting to use a RPubs code to create a box plot chart with cld.The example I have is great, but I am struggling to adjust it to include a second explanatory variable. Can someone provide me with a way to change this so I can have charts for my conference. Thank you!!

```
Tk <- group_by(Clean.Data, Lbs.Acre, Cultivar) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(Stem.wt), quant = quantile(Stem.wt, probs = 0.75,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
arrange(desc(mean))
```

Errors I have gotten include:

> "summarise() has grouped output by 'Lbs.Acre'. You can override using the `.groups argument."

and

> "trim' must be numeric of length one".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from dput(Tk), if that is not too large. Also include all the relevant code (what is 'cld' ?). And an indication of the desired output - your title mentions a table, but the question refers to a boxplot, so what are you trying to make? One last thing, the first 'error' is not an error, it's a message.